# Angular unit test: TypeError: $controller is not a function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, webpack

am setting up unit test for Angular application build with webpack how ever am getting this error when am running my first simple test.

```
TypeError: $controller is not a function
```

The controller code like this :

```
 (function() {
  'use strict';
    angular
      .module('dpServerV2WebappRev2App.controllers')
      .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
        MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
        function MainCtrl($scope) {
          $scope.x = 'x';
      }
    })();
```

Where the test look like this:

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('dpServerV2WebappRev2App.controllers'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.brand', function () {
        it('should match the brand portal name', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            expect($scope.x).toEqual('x');
        }); 
    });

});
```

Just to clear things more I have comment out the test code where I test the `$scope.x` and replace it with this:

```
expect(1).toEqual(1);
```

Therefor I got this error

```
 at Error (native)
        at node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
        at node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:40:134
        at r (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
        at g (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:39:222)
        at Object.db [as injector] (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:43:246)
        at Object.workFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3067:5
```

I have commented out my module injection in the test and now the test is passing however when including the module is still getting the above error:
The new test code that cause no problems:

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {
  describe('$scope.brand', function () {
        it('should match the brand portal name', function () {
            expect(1).toEqual(1);
        }); 
    });
```

Since it seems config problem to me I'll add my Karma config file:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'assets/app.bundle.js',
      'app/*.js',
      'tests/**/*.test.js'

    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './assets/app.bundle.js': ['webpack'],    
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

     webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Comment: what is your angular version? have you install `angular-mocks`?

Comment: Hi the Angular version is 1.5.7, yes angular mock is installed and included in the Karma.conf.js file as well as Angular

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia please check my question editing.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the angular mocks, sometimes is very strange when we deal with services. Try this

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {

      beforeEach(module('dpServerV2WebappRev2App.controllers'));

      var controllerInjector, myController;

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
        controllerInjector = $controller;
      }));

      describe('$scope.brand', function () {
            it('should match the brand portal name', function () {
                var $scope = {};
                myController = controllerInjector('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
                expect($scope.x).toEqual('x');
            }); 
        });

});
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/jAgNpW